# How to allow file upload for Anonymous user in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to allow anonymous user to upload files in SharePoint.
After making some research, I wrote this codes to allow anonymous user to upload. but anonymous user can't log in and is asked to log in.
Help me please. What is wrong with my codes ?

```
    public string CreateSPFilet(string spServerURL, string tempLibrary, string folder, Stream fileStream, bool overwrite)
    {
        string strError = "";
        string fileName = "";
        try
        {                
            if (!SPSite.Exists(new Uri(spServerURL)))
            {
                strError += ERROR01;
            }
            else
            {
                SPSite tempSite = new SPSite(spServerURL);
                SPUserToken systoken = tempSite.SystemAccount.UserToken;
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(spServerURL, systoken))
                {
                    SPWeb oWebsite = site.OpenWeb();
                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                   {
                       using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
                       {
                           using (SPWeb eevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb(oWebsite.ID))
                           {
                               oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                               string targetUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(oWebsite.ServerRelativeUrl, tempLibrary);
                               SPFolder target = oWebsite.GetFolder(targetUrl);
                               SPFileCollection files = target.Files;
                               SPFile file = target.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, overwrite);
                               oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                           }
                       }
                   });
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the last using statement you need to use the references to the elevated object instead of the other ones. Like so:

```
eevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;   
string targetUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(eevatedWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, tempLibrary);                                
SPFolder target = eevatedWeb.GetFolder(targetUrl);                                   
SPFileCollection files = target.Files;
SPFile file = target.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, overwrite);                                
eevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

You also need to dispose of the objects tempSite and oWebSite, since they are not disposed by your above code.